# WebSocket connection to wss failed in production only(front end and back end on different domains)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, vercel

i've successfully created a chat app on my own lol, my front end and back end are both deployed on vercel, everything is working fine locally except that the socket connection is not being established in production
my backend api url is https://chat-app-bice-ten.vercel.app/
my frontend api url is https://chattin.vercel.app/

I get the following error, it keeps occuring periodically
WebSocket connection to 'wss://chat-app-bice-ten.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket'

SERVER CODE

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://chattin.vercel.app",
  },
});
```

CLIENT CODE

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("https://chat-app-bice-ten.vercel.app", {
  transports: ["websocket"],
});
```

export default socket;

Tried many things, searched alot but all in vain

Comment: Look in the network tab in your browser's developer tools. There should be more information about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, the problem is that Vercel does not support WebSocket connections. Do you know any other free hosting services that support WebSocket communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can deploy a websocket server on Vercel according to their doc:

https://vercel.com/guides/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections

> Serverless Functions on Vercel are stateless and have a maximum execution duration. As a result, it is not possible to maintain a WebSocket connection to a Serverless Function.

There are a few option out there to make it work: [Ably](https://www.ably.com), [Pusher](https://www.pusher.com), [Shippr](https://www.getshippr.com) (disclaimer: I work for the last one, there is a free plan - happy to onboard you :))

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Does that mean I will have to get rid of the existing socket.io code and replace it with one of libraries you mentioned (I'm thinking of pusher) ? Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, you will not ba able to  maintain a persistent connection and have your own websocket server, even if you set your own custom server (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server) "A custom server cannot be deployed on Vercel"

Comment: Alright, thanks alot for your help. I'm on my to implementing Pusher, wish me luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked when I did it this way.

I don't know why, but `import socketIo` doesn't work for me.

SERVER CODE

```
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "https://mychat.vercel.app",
    },
});
```

NOTE: I made this server run like this on a VPS and not on Vercel, but I think this could help.