# Problem while deploying project on vercel

Tags: javascript, html, express, websocket, backend

I made a project white-board where the changes you make on your board reflects to all users. What happens is when you perform a mouse down and mouse move, you send this to the server using socket.io and then the server sends it to all the users including urself and the changes happen. When i tried to host this on Vercel i am having errors with the backend.

HTML that deals with backend

```
    <script>
        let socket=io.connect("https://white-board-zeta.vercel.app/");
    </script>
    <script defer src="./tools.js"></script>
    <script src="./canvas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend JS

```
const express = require("express");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");


const app=express();
// app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.static("./frontend"));

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
let server=app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("listening to port " + port);
})

let io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
// let io = socket(server);

io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log("Made socket connection");
    socket.on("beginpath",(data)=>{
        io.sockets.emit("beginpath",data);
    })
    socket.on("drawstroke",(data)=>{
        io.sockets.emit("drawstroke",data);
    })
    socket.on("performUndoRedo",(data)=>{
        io.sockets.emit("performUndoRedo",data);
    })
})
```

I tried many ways from youtube but they didnt work.

Comment: Ok, but how can we help you, if you do not share what the error(s) is/are? Debugging details are crucial. Please edit your question adding them

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be the same than this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931526/websocket-connection-to-wss-failed-in-production-onlyfront-end-and-back-end-on/76934386#76934386)
You can deploy a websocket server on Vercel according to their doc:

https://vercel.com/guides/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections

> Serverless Functions on Vercel are stateless and have a maximum execution duration. As a result, it is not possible to maintain a WebSocket connection to a Serverless Function.

Comment: I am very new to backend and the js of the backend i took from online. Can you please elaborate the term Serverless Functions and how it relates to my code and if there is a possibility to deploy my app on vercel. Thank you.